# How to solve this Basic probability question?

Tags: probability

I have started learning probability. I came across the following question and wanted to know how to solve this problem.

Suppose a population is divided into two groups: aggressive drivers and non­aggressive drivers. 40% of the population are aggressive drivers while 60% are non­aggressive drivers. The probability of an aggressive driver getting into 3 accidents in one year is 15%. The probability of a non­aggressive driver getting into 3 accidents in one year is 5%. John is known to have 3 accidents in the past year. What is the probability that he is (a) an aggressive driver, and (b) a non­aggressive driver?

Comment: Can you write down Bayes' rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this like you do any word problem.  Assign some relevant variables, and then write down some equations that relate them.  Let $X$ be the event that a driver is aggressive, and let $Y$ be the event that a driver has $3$ accidents in the past year.  We are told$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(X)&=.4\\
\Pr(\bar{X})&=.6\\
\Pr(Y|X)&=.15\\
\Pr(Y|\bar X)&=.05
\end{align}
$$
and we are asked to find $\Pr(X|Y)$.

Since this is a question about conditional probability, we think of Bayes' rule:$$\Pr(X|Y)=\frac{\Pr(Y|X)\Pr(X)}{\Pr(Y)}$$  Of course, we need to know $\Pr(Y)$ to apply this formula.  We get this from the law of total probability:
$$\Pr(Y)=\Pr(X)\Pr(Y|X)+\Pr(\bar X)\Pr(Y|\bar X)$$

Take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. I got stuck on finding Pr(Y). This is very helpful.

Comment: @MageshN If the answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark.  That way it no longer shows as unresolved.